# Webhttrack defualt web browser

Tags: firefox, default-browser, httrack

for whatever reason after I installed links terminal browser on my machine the web interface to httrack only opens in links which isn't very fun at all to to use. This issue can be recreated by installing webhttrack from apt prior to installing links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question first use

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/webhttrack
```

then find the line :

```
BROWSEREXE=
```

change it to

```
BROWSEREXE="firefox" // or the name of the browser you want
```

then find the line

```
SRCHBROWSEREXE= ... // a long string of browser names should follow
```

comment this out should look like the following

```
#SRCHBROWSEREXE= ... /// string of browser names to follow
```

exit and save changes and it should run in the browser you want